# How to build breakpad for windows without errors? What is the difference between breakpad and crashpad

Tags: google-breakpad

I am getting below error while building breakpad in windows.
c:\breakpad\src>src\tools\gyp\gyp.bat src\client\windows\breakpad_client.gyp
gyp: Cycles in .gyp file dependency graph detected:

Comment: Some patching is required to get breakpad to build on Windows, see [this article](https://github.com/d1vanov/quentier/wiki/Building-and-installation-of-Quentier's-dependencies#building-google-breakpad) of mine where I describe what exactly needs to be done.

Comment: great. Thanks Dmitry.